# Closure of Integers under multiplication and rational exponentiation

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, complex-numbers, examples-counterexamples

What is the closure of the Integers under a finite number of multiplications and rational exponentiations?

For example, $3^{1/2}$, $i = -1^{1/2}$, and $\frac{-1+i \sqrt(3)}{2} = 1^{1/3}$ all in this closure.

Are there any complex numbers provably *not* in this closure?  Can you describe the entire set with a simple, closed-form solution?

Comment: $\pi$ comes to mind...

Comment: With infinite multiplications we would get arbitrarily close to any real number; is that enough to show that a particular number is an element of the closure?  Once any real number is an element, then every imaginary number is also.  And we could get arbitrarily close to every argument (vector angle in the complex plane), so then the whole complex plane is available.  But it all hinges on "is arbitrarily close good enough for closure?"

Comment: How would you converge to $\pi$ using only multiplications/divisions and rational exponentiation?

Comment: Do you mean *topological* closure instead of *algebraic* closure?

Comment: @lhf I'm pretty sure the OP just means the smallest set containing $\mathbb{Z}$ closed under the given operations.  That is, the smallest set $S \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq S$ and $x \cdot y \in S$ and $x^q \in S$ for all $x,y \in S$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we are given real number $r$ and let $0\lt \epsilon \lt 1$ be given.  Assume that there is a function $z=\log_y x$ for real numbers $x,y$ which gives the exact real number $z$ such that $y^z=x$.  Let $k=\log_2 r$.  Choose $p\over q$ as a rational approximation of $k$ such that $\epsilon\lt \dfrac{2^{p\over q}}r\lt\frac 1\epsilon$.

By this method, it is clear that any real number can be approximated as nearly as desired.  By similar mechanisms, we can approximate any complex number as nearly as we wish by multiplying by a root of unity.

Comment: Agreed.  And what if you have only a finite number of operations?

Comment: My answer here addresses the situation where there is one exponentiation operation invoked.  You comments on your question indicated that an infinite number of operations might also be of interest; for that case, it would be possible to create a "limit" scenario and fully include every real number (and thus every complex number) in the resulting set.  With a finite number of operations, the resulting set is limited to "the integers to any rational exponent times any rational root of unity."

Answer (score 1):

Given your $1^{1/3}$ example, I think that the set you describe is the set of all complex numbers of the form $\omega a^{1/m}$, where $\omega$ is a root of unit and  $a$ and $m$ are positive integers.

This can be proved by induction on the *complexity* of a number, which is the smallest number of elementary steps (multiplication and rational exponentiaton) required to produce the number.

Comment: No ... addition and subtraction are expressly prohibited.